# How to add IBOutlet of a NSTextField in a custom View correctly in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, uistoryboard, iboutlet, custom-view

I try to create an outlet from a `NSTextView`, which is a subview of my `NSView` derived custom class called `GeneralView`. I want to connect this outlet to my `GeneralView` class but `Xcode` doesn't like it. I get the following screen:

[image]

In this image, I want to connect an `@IBOutlet` from the `NSTextField` that contains '0000' to 'tfLiid' in GeneralView.

It only works if I create a `@IBOutlet` to the `ViewController`.
But I have like more than 50 views (textfields, progress bars, checkboxes and so on...) I need to update, so I want to split those views in 3 parent views and keep the ViewController clean by holding only the 3 parent (or group) views.

The image below makes you understand more of what I tried to achieve (I hope).
[image]

I just don't know how to get this done right in Xcode, it's not a programming problem. Thank you.

Comment: The popover is related to Cocoa Bindings, not to outlet/action.

Comment: Ok, because it doesn't look the same, that's why it's a bit strange to me. So how can I create an outlet? Ctrl+MouseClick is what I used always (when developing iOS apps). btw, if I do this to ViewController, than it works.

Comment: Try to create the IBOutlet manually in the custom class and connect it.

Comment: It gives the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, just by experimenting trying out. I just couldn't let it go. Anyway, you have to drag from the little @IBOutlet circle (on the line number) to the view you want to connect it to. I don't know why the other way around doesn't work, there must be a reason for it.

An image below for a visual example:
[image]

Comment: That's what I suggested 

Comment: "Try to create the IBOutlet manually in the custom class and connect it" I really did that, normally Xcode automatically creates the IBOutlet stub, but it didn't. So I added manually myself and dragged from the View in IB to the IBOutlet in code. But that didn't work, I had to do it the other way around, meaning dragging from the code to the view in IB. Anyway, you pushed me to the right direction 